# Create a matrix from two individual lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
list2 = [a, b, c]
```

and I want to combine them into 2D list called `list3`. List three should basically become `[[1][a], [2][b],[3][c]`. (I think that's how it works though I could be mistaken).

I want to be able to print certain parts of list 3 by using "`print(list3[x][y])`". Does anyone know how to combine the two lists and define them as `list3`?

Comment: by `[1][a]` do you mean a pair `(1, a)` or list of 2 fields `[1, a]` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> list3 = [[[x],[y]] for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]
>>> list3
[[[1], ['a']], [[2], ['b']], [[3], ['c']]]
```

Comment: There is extra nesting that is not necessary.